# Count the number of replies from a comment in a given post using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have a sample comments table below:

```
id  | parent_id | post_id
 1      0            1
 2      0            1
 3      1            1
 4      2            1
 5      1            1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get all comments (parent_id=0) based on post_id, and count the total replies at the same time. When a query is executed it should display like the result below:

```
 id 1 has 2 replies
 id 2 has 1 reply
```

Here is my sample query below and it gets all comments from the given post but the problem is, I am not sure how to count at the same time in one query.

```
 Comment::where('parent_id', '=', 0)
          ->where('post_id', $postId)
          ->get();
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a method in your Comment model class.
As follows:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment','parent_id');
}
```

Then you can get the number of replies using the following code:

```
$comments = Comment::where('parent_id', '=', 0)
      ->where('post_id', $postId)
      ->withCount('replies')
      ->get();
```

In this case, you can access the number of comments with the following code:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment){
    $countOfReplies = $comment->replies_count;
}
```

I hope it helps